# jsaddle-dom import error suggests adding dependency I've already added

Tags: ghcjs

When trying to compile my `ghcjs`/`jsaddle` based Haskell website, I get

```
Main.hs:20:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘GHCJS.DOM.Element’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘jsaddle-dom-0.9.2.0’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘jsaddle-dom’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

even though `jsaddle-dom` is already in the `build-depends` of my cabal file.

So I can't do what the error message suggests.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `build-depends: ghcjs-dom` instead of `build-depends: jsaddle-dom` in your cabal file.

This is because `ghcjs-dom` is the multiplexer between the real `ghcjs-dom-jsffi` and `jsaddle-dom`.

Check out the [ghcjs-dom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-dom-0.9.2.0/ghcjs-dom.cabal) cabal file to see that.

Why is ghc's error message so misleading? Thanks to `jonored` from the `#reflex-frp` freenode IRC channel for this explanation:

> ghcjs-dom is just a reference to the module in jsaddle on that platform.
>   so it's not where it actually canonically *is*, and ghc tells you about where it *is*. But you want ghcjs-dom, so that it tells you the ghcjs-based implementation on ghcjs.